# At which point Hibernate Generates Tables?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I'm having a look at spring-data-jpa (actually my first time using entityManager)
and i haven't seen any error but entityManager doesn't seem to have generated a table for Entity class `Account`. here is my application context (project-model-config.xml) in maven main/resources/META-INF folder

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:mysql.hibernate.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:mysql.jdbc.properties</value>
            <!--<value>classpath:liquibase.properties</value>-->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManger" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <!--<property name="generateDdl" value="true" />-->
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bla.bla.model.domain"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<jpa:repositories base-package="com.bla.bla.model.dao"/>
```

the persistence.xml (sibling of project-model-config.xml in the main/resources/META-INF ) also looks like this

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
 <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
</persistence>
```

properties mysql.hibernate.properties/ mysql.jdbc.properties

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=mypass
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectjava
```

The package com.bla.bla.model.domain contains an Entity Account

```
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.util.Date;
   import javax.persistence.Basic;
   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private Long ID;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
}
```

after a succesfull built (maven) there is no table generated. I even added a single test using simple assert.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/project-model-config.xml"})
public class AccountDAOTest {

 @Test
 public void testSetup(){
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
 }
}
```

So am confused a little bit about how to get the Entity generated i can't see why it can't.
Can any one see the problem here?

Comment: What is **project-model-config.xml?** You got to load the **applicationContext** right?

Comment: @ManuPK sorry for the lack of precision. it's the same `applicationContext` that i'm showing at the first part of my post.i've edited it a bit to be more clear.

Comment: Did you try the below answer? I did not see any comments or other answers. Please upvote / accept the answers if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Generates Tables when the **Entity mappings are loaded**. Which means your case it should generate the tables.

This looks like an issue in spring with `jpaVendorAdapter` told in their [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6836).
Also there is an SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4307690/507864).

Now, I am not sure if you need `jpaVendorAdapter` in the application context. I did not use it, nor did I find it on Spring [API docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/orm.html). It is not mandatory, let it be initialized to the default [value](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setJpaVendorAdapter%28org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter%29).

Remove that mapping and try executing the code.