# Spring Boot voodoo required instantiating JPA with DataNucleus and Hikari

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datanucleus

Any help getting this config to work would be welcome.

I am trying to take over the automatic connection pool, datasource and JPA configuration from `Spring Boot` to allow me to bring `DataNucleus` into the mix instead of `Hibernate`.

My approach is to code up the pieces `Boot` says are missing on a trial and error basis. I had to remove the Hibernate dependencies to allow DataNucleus to run.

Maybe I've now coded up too much or maybe not I'm not far enough.

Spring falls over with the error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
[huge SNIP]
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: 
    Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'symbolRepositoryImpl': 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityManager'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: 
    expected single matching bean but found 2:
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1
[SNIP]
2017-06-01 09:43:09.675 ERROR 9108 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field entityManager in com.bp.gis.tardis.repository.SymbolRepositoryImpl 
    required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0: defined by method 'createSharedEntityManager' in null
    - org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1: defined by method 'createSharedEntityManager' in null


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, 
or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I could spend hours debugging this further but the breakpoint comes in the initialisation of one of the repositories which should have an entityManager injected.

This is what I'm manually instantiating:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"org.adam.repository"}
)
public class DataSourceConfig {


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "adam.datasource")
    public AdamDataSourceProperties getDataSourceProperties() {
        return new AdamDataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        AdamDataSourceProperties props = getDataSourceProperties();
        return new HikariDataSource(props.getHikariConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEmfBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("adam");
        return emfBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = getEmfBean();
        return emfBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    }

}
```

My `AdamDatasourceProperties` is initialised by Spring using the "adam.datasource" prefixed values in `application.properties`, and it can then create a `HikariConfig` object to use to instantiate the `HikariDataSource`. That bit is actually fine, it's the entity manager factory that is probably causing issues - or something else.

I've got no evidence that my last method `getEmf()` is actually helping.

Also, I'm dubious that the error

> Required a single bean, but 2 were found

or the suggested action are helpful - I don't fancy going into the Spring source code in order to annotate one of those methods on Spring's `SharedEntityManagerCreator` as `@Primary`.

**UPDATE**
`DataNucleus` won't run if it finds other JPA API classes on the classpath - it insists on its own version of the persistence API - hence removing the Hibernate packages was necessary.

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: 
    Found Meta-Data for class org.adam.entity.TimeSeriesEntity 
    but this class is either not enhanced or you have multiple copies 
    of the persistence API jar in your CLASSPATH!! 
    Make sure all persistable classes are enhanced before running 
    DataNucleus and/or the CLASSPATH is correct.
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl
             .initialiseClassMetaData(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2814)
```

so I have excluded Hibernate from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and the error disappears.

Comment: no idea about all of that Spring stuff, but doesn't LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass define your JPA provider, hence maybe you don't have to exclude other providers from the CLASSPATH? DataNucleus, after all, simply obeys the JPA spec in having a "provider".

Comment: what is "it insists on its own version of the persistence API"? you give no versions of anything here. I don't see anything in their "API jar" that is not in the JPA 2.1 spec. Clearly the JPA expert group do not publish a standard JPA API so providers have all created their own API jar.

Comment: @NeilStockton DataNucleus doesn't have to have a persistence.xml, does it?

Comment: DataNucleus supports full JPA, so you provide a `persistence.xml` just like the JPA spec tells you to. Clearly Spring may be doing something else there to generate an EMF without a `persistence.xml` by passing in a PersistenceUnitInfo

Comment: May be [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684197/why-did-i-need-to-define-a-hibernate-jpa-vendor-adapter-in-my-spring-application) will help, or [this](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/guides/jdo/springframework/index.html)?

Comment: @manish I had seen those 2 links already but thanks. I found the answer, I'll post it later. The `JpaVendorAdapter` is not necessary because `DataNucleus` requires a real `persistence.xml`, and I can put the config for it in there. Or better said, if `DataNucleus` doesn't require the xml file, I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: Errm no I dont think you can say that, since the EMF constructor for JavaEE environments doesn't "need" any `persistence.xml` file present (see https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/api/jpa/JPAEntityManagerFactory.java#L141 ) and that takes in a `PersistenceUnitInfo`. Spring could easily use that (and maybe it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` method name to `entityManagerFactory`:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("adam");
    return emfBean;
}
```

and to enable testing, I have to copy this `@Configuration` class and change the EMF method to accept Spring's test database:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("adam");
    return emfBean;
}
```

That `@Qualifier` is for the sake of Intellij whose Spring facet complains about 2 candidates for injection here.

I also discovered that with this configuration, the repository/DTO dependency injection for the `EntityManager` doesn't work with `@Autowired`. It has to be the native-JPA annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

With my previous Hibernate and OpenJPA configurations, Spring was happy to inject its own self-instantiated `EntityManager` in the presence of `@Autowire`.

This adds more fuel to my beef with Spring. It just too often doesn't do what it says on the tin. The Spring tests should find the `@Configuration` classes in the package hierarchy, but doesn't - I need to use `@Import`. Spring should also find dependency injection candidates based on type (`EntityManager`, `DataSource` etc) but it doesn't - in some cases they have to be produced by methods named a particular name or with `@Bean` annotations declaring a name.

Still, it's done.