# JTASessionContext being used with JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, jta

Using hibernate in my application, and everytime I do a transaction, I get this warning. It is spamming my logs.

```
JTASessionContext being used with JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()
```

I think it is caused by `hibernate.current_session_context_class`property.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>

    <mapping class="foo.bar.Class1" />
    <mapping class="foo.bar.Class2" />
    <mapping class="foo.bar.Class3" />
    <mapping class="foo.bar.Class4" />
    <mapping class="foo.bar.Class5" />
</session-factory>
```

Is it something I should be worried about? If not, how can I stop the warning from appearing.

Comment: Need to see you complete hibernate config file or your complete <hibernate-config> tag...

Comment: @DarkHorse : sure, updated initial question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware,it is not possible to configure Hibernate JPA with JTA support using Spring unless you provide a persistence.xml in order to configure the datasource as JTA.
Perhaps some thing like this will help you get rid of the warning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="something" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>blah blah</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="blah blah"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>          
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_statement"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I would also suggest you to disable **allowLocalTransactions** so that your code will run as transactional all the time.

Comment: How do I load configure my project to load stuff from `persistence.xml`?

Comment: I suppose you already have an 'entityManager' bean in your applicationContext.Then add the following property to that:
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="something"/>. You could place persistence.xml somewhere like your META-INF

Comment: No I have no beans. Isn't applicationContext `Spring` thing?

Comment: My mistake, I thought you are using Spring framework :) So simply replace your hibernate config with the above xml.And add necessary properties ofcourse.

Comment: When I had my old hibernate cfg, for every file I had to provide a mapping as in original post, how do I do it in persistence.xml?

Comment: `hibernate.archive.autodetection` will do it for you. You could also put `<class>sample.domain.User</class>` for each class before properties tag

Comment: You can configure Hibernate with JTA support along with Spring without defining a persistence.xml. Take a look to this question i posted some time ago,it describes how i achieve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546291/when-migrating-from-jboss-as-7-1-1-to-eap-6-2-causes-spring-defined-entitymanage