# JBoss 7 Spring JPA + Hibernate Application: no transaction is in progress

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jboss7.x

I'm trying to develop a simple Payroll Application with Spring 3.2 using JPA and Hibernate and the JPA Provider. I'm deploying it on the JBoss AS 7 Server. I keep getting the following error:

```
16:42:13,811 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/PayrollApp].[payrollApp]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet payrollApp threw exception: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:993) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.colenso.payrollapp.persistence.daos.GenericDAO.add(GenericDAO.java:34) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.colenso.payrollapp.service.HRServiceImpl.addEmployee(HRServiceImpl.java:29) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.addEmployee(Unknown Source)
    at com.colenso.payrollapp.controllers.PaySlipController.showHomePage(PaySlipController.java:42) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

I'm using Spring 3.2 without any **persistence.xml** file.
Relevant parts of my **Spring App Config** file:

```
<!--    Turn on annotation driven features of spring-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!--<context:annotation-config />-->

    <!--Enable Spring to detect the Controllers and other components automatically and configure them as beans-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.colenso.payrollapp"  />
<!--Look up the Datasource that's been configured in JBoss as a JNDI datasource-->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" resource-ref="false" />



    <!--Configuration for the Entity Manger Factory-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">  
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.colenso.payrollapp.persistence.entities" />  
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>  
        </property>  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>  
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="payrollPU" />
    </bean>  

    <util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">  
        <entry key="show_sql" value="true" />  
        <entry key="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>  
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>  
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
    </util:map>


    <!--Enable injection of the Entity Manager-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <!--Enable Spring's Exception Translation Mechanism-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>



    <!--Configuration for the Transactions-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

As you can see, I'm pulling the Datasource that I have configured in the **standalone.xml** file.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class PaySlipController {

    @Autowired
    HRService hrService;


    public PaySlipController() {
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Employee employee1;
        employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.setFirstName("FN");
        employee1.setLastName("LN");
        Calendar myDOB = new GregorianCalendar(1965, 6, 15);
        employee1.setDateOfBirth(myDOB);


        hrService.addEmployee(employee1);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

I'm following the `The type-safe generic DAO pattern` as mentioned in this article [enter link description here](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/09/jpa-implementation-patterns-data-access-objects/)
Here is all the relevant code:
**Interface**
    public interface GenericDAOInterface {

```
void add(E entitry);

void remove(E entity);

E findById(K id);
```

}

**Implementation**

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<E, K> implements GenericDAOInterface<E, K> {

protected Class entityClass;
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public GenericDAO() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

@Override
public void add(E entity) {
    if (entityManager==null)
        System.out.println("Entity Manager Not Initialised!!");
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
}

@Override
public void remove(E entity) {
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}

@Override
public E findById(K id) {
    return (E) entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
}
```

}

**Interface:**

```
public interface EmployeeDAO extends GenericDAOInterface<Employee, Integer>{

}
```

**Implementation**

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends GenericDAO<Employee, Integer> implements EmployeeDAO{

}
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface HRService {

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
@Component
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class HRServiceImpl implements HRService{

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDao;


    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee){
        employeeDao.add(employee);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem based on the answer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456622/jtasessioncontext-being-used-with-jdbctransactionfactory-auto-flush-will-not-op)

It's given that to use JTA it is mandatory to a **persistence.xml**. So that's what I ended up doing.

My **persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <class>com.colenso.payrollapp.persistence.entities.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="blah blah"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>          
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_statement"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My changed **Spring Context xml**:

```
<!--********************DataBase Configurations********************************-->

    <!--Look up the Datasource that's been configured in JBoss as a JNDI datasource-->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" resource-ref="false" />



    <!--Configuration for the Entity Manger Factory-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">  
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.colenso.payrollapp.persistence.entities" />  
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>  
        </property>  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>  
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
    </bean>  

    <util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">  
        <entry key="show_sql" value="true" />  
        <entry key="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>  
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>  
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />  
        <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
    </util:map>


    <!--Enable injection of the Entity Manager-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <!--Enable Spring's Exception Translation Mechanism-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>



    <!--Configuration for the Transactions-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >
        <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
        <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 1):

to enable JTA without persistence.xml, you need to set jtaDatsource properties instead of datasource:

```
<bean id="pcdEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="pcdDataSource"
    p:jtaDataSource-ref="pcdDataSource" 
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
    p:jpaProperties-ref="jpaProperties" 
    p:persistenceUnitName="pcd-unit"
    p:packagesToScan="com.compay.x.db.entity" />
```