# JBoss, RestEasy, Spring dependency injection failing

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, resteasy

I am just about to give up on JBoss and go back to Tomcat but I thought I would ask the wise world of stackoverflow before jumping ship.  My apologies as there will be a lot of code/xml/logs pasted here.  There must be something simple that I am missing?

I have started a new Resteasy project on JBoss 7.1.1 and currently have 2 endpoints as seen below.

```
@Named
@Path("/v1/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @GET
    public Response getUsers() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("someUsername");
        user.setEmail("user@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("thepassword");
        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(user);

        return responseBuilder.build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createUser(User user) {
        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = null;

        try {
            userService.register(user);
            responseBuilder = Response.created(null);
        } catch (UserException ue) {
            if (ue.getMessage().equals(ErrorCode.USER_REGISTRATION_FIELD_MISSING)) {
                responseBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.fromStatusCode(422));
                responseBuilder.entity(ue.getMessage());
            } else {
                responseBuilder = Response.serverError();
                responseBuilder.entity(ue.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return responseBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

The @Get /v1/users works fine.  My problem is that the userService is not injected and I am getting NullPointerExceptions when calling @POST /v1/users at the userService.register(user) call.  Stack trace below

```
17:17:05,669 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/api].[Resteasy]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
... JBoss/Resteasy attempting to handle exception, left out to reduce bloat

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at au.com.codecave.api.UserResource.createUser(UserResource.java:48) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
... 19 more
```

I followed this [JBoss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Spring_Integration.html) to setup my web.xml and have setup my context.xml files as I normally do.

Web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <!-- Auto scan for REST services ad providers -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/bizniz-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

bizniz-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="persistence-context.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="au.com.codecave.service"/>

</beans>
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Named
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Inject
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public User register(User user) throws UserException {

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail()) || StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) {
            log.error("Mandatory registration field was empty.  Email: {}, Username: {}", user.getEmail(), user.getUsername());
            throw new UserException(ErrorCode.USER_REGISTRATION_FIELD_MISSING.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            userDao.create(user);
        } catch (DataException de) {
            throw new UserException(de);
        }

        return user;
    }
```

I don't see any exceptions in the startup log about instantiating any of the beans so I don't think that is the problem, and I am seeing the message below which I assume means Spring initialised correctly

```
17:16:46,003 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@54287575: defining beans [userDaoImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,dataSource,jdbcTemplate,userServiceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
17:16:46,121 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 783 ms
```

I have been scouring the web all day looking for a solution but just can not seem to find one.  Version details below.

JBoss AS 7.1.1
Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE (Was 4 but realised resteasy Bootstrap only works with 3 [see issue here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1012?_sscc=t))
Resteasy-spring 3.0.8.Final

Please let me know if more information is required.  Thanks all.

Comment: I am facing the same problem !! Could you please post how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of null pointer exception issue.

Step1:
Instead of using the SpringContextLoaderListener try the default ContextLoaderListener from spring framework in web.xml

```
 <listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Step2:
In POM file add the below 2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
<version>3.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Step3:
And in bizniz-context.xml add the below bean definition above component-scan

```
 <bean class="org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessorServletAware"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is the problem, but initialization JAX-RS in a JEE environment requires little manual configuration. Instead of configuring the servlet in the web.xml (which is to make it work on a non-JEE environment such as Tomcat), you simply need an Application class like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/REST")  
public class JaxrsApplication extends Application {  
}
```

The existence of this class (annotated with ApplicationPath and extending Application) will trigger JBoss to initialize the JAX-RS subsystem. Name it as you want and map it to whatever URL you want of course.

Documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/JAX-RS+Reference+Guide

But I see you use Spring, which makes me question if what I'm saying here is the whole truth.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  JAX-RS seems to be initialised properly as the @GET endpoint works fine.  I think the Resteasy servlet takes care of the initialisation for me.  I gave your suggestion a go anyway but I still ended up with the NullPointerException.  For some reason it looks like Spring instantiates all the beans correctly but they just don't seem to be injected anywhere.

Comment: Then I'd rather look for the problem in the area of Spring and not JBoss / JAX-RS. Sorry, I can't be of help there :( In any case the servlet is not the way to go, what I posted is as that is in the official JBoss documentation.

Comment: All good, thanks for the attempt!  The servlet is from the offical Jboss docs too (JBoss documentation link in the question).  Both approaches seem to work for me for Non spring integrated endpoints.  The problem is definitely in the wiring between Spring and JBoss.   The `SpringContextLoaderListener` should wire Spring into the application from what I understand so I have probably configured something wrong somewhere.  I just can't find it yet.

Comment: Perhaps this thread can give a clue, it looks like it contains pretty complete configuration examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260328/jboss-7-spring-jpa-hibernate-application-no-transaction-is-in-progress