# @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) doesn't create a new connection on JBoss EAP

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, jboss-eap-7

I have a need to dynamically switch datasource in runtime (read/write to multiple MariaDB databases). I'm using [multi-tenancy concept for the same](https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa).

I have not been able to get it to work for the below simple scenario though. For the first invocation of `myService.persist()` a connection is requested by the Spring and hence a connection associated with `db1` is returned as expected. However, for the second invocation, no new connection is requested and existing connection associated with `db1` is being used.

```java
public class MainClass {
    
    ..
    
    public void main() {
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("db1");
        myService.persist();

        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("db2");
        myService.persist();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    ..

    // Method is correctly declared as public and is being called from another class
    // to ensure proxy application
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void persist() {
        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        entity.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        entity.setLastUpdated(new Date());


        repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

The application is built on Spring Boot 2.7.17 and is being deployed on JBoss EAP 7.3 container. Datasource is configured using JNDI with below configuration in `standalone.xml`. I have not configured any Transaction manager in code explicitly.

```xml
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/datasources/db1" pool-name="db1" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://myhost:3306/db1</connection-url>
    <driver>maria</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>*******</user-name>
        <password>******</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <set-tx-query-timeout>true</set-tx-query-timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>300</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>10</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <query-timeout>300</query-timeout>
        <allocation-retry>3</allocation-retry>
        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>300</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
    </timeout>
</datasource>
```

I do see the below log in start up log. Could it have something to do with it?

```
Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JBoss 7 Spring JPA + Hibernate Application: no transaction is in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260328/jboss-7-spring-jpa-hibernate-application-no-transaction-is-in-progress)

Comment: It's has chances to be related, yes: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/internal/NoJtaPlatform.java

Comment: @seenukarthi No, in my case I'm not getting such error. It seems be either starting another transaction in the existing connection or not starting new connection at all.

Comment: when the second *.persist()* do you get any exception ? or it does not save any data ? I would enable debug log and try to debug and see if there is any other warning or error log saying more details about persist?

Comment: Why are you trying to run a springboot application in JavaEE?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that @seenukarthi's comment has a proper link. Fillow the link and take a look at the configuration.
You wrote here that you didn't declare any transaction manager, but it's strongly required since you use `@Transactional`.

> When using the @Transactional annotation in Spring, you must add the
> following line to your Spring configuration file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

> The transaction-manager property holds a reference to the transaction
> manager bean defined in the Spring configuration file. This code tells
> Spring to use the @Transaction annotation when applying the
> transaction interceptor. Without it, the @Transactional annotation is
> ignored, resulting in no transaction being used in your code.

[Here is a nice article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170213005145/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ts1/index.html) about transaction management.