# When migrating from JBoss AS 7.1.1 to EAP 6.2 causes spring-defined entityManagerFactory to fail when loading

Tags: spring, jpa, jboss

I'm developing an application using JPA 2.1 with spring 4.0.2. Jboss server provides a JNDI Datasource.

I've defined this entityManager in services.xml in order to avoid the use of a persistence.xml file:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="projectDataSourceTaget" jndi-name="${jndi.datasourceName}"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    depends-on="flyway">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="projectEntityManager" />
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="projectDataSourceTaget" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">
          org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <!-- validate | update | create | create-drop -->
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.use_revision_entity_with_native_id">false</prop>
        <prop key="javax.persistence.transactionType">JTA</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Althought this worked fine in Jboss 7.1.1 when changing to EAP 6.2 it fails to initialize the service:

```
17:27:17,061 WARN  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
17:27:17,079 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Project.war#Project": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Project.war#Project": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Project] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: GaIA] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1822)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1780)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 9 more
```

I'm msising something? i've tried several changes in this configuration but nothing seems to work. Maybe LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is not right supported on JBoss EAP 6.2?

Comment: Oh if forgot some part of the spring config file. The value of ${jndi.datasourceName} is filled from a properties file accessed automatically due to:  `code`
    <context:property-placeholder  
        location="file:${ENV_CONFIG}/project_environment.properties" />  
`code`
 
  
And also ENV_CONFIG is a well defined environment variable. As i told it worked perfectly in JBoss AS 7.1.1 but EAP 6.2 doesn't seem to work the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got the problem: In a older version of the project there was a persistence.xml defined that was deployed in JBoss for days, even when a clean deploy was made (i guess this was beacause a file system malfunction). This make the JBoss loader to mess up with entityManagers defined in both persistence.xml and services.xml.