# Getting "no transaction is in progress" when calling em.flush();

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hi i am trying to integrate jpa with spring mvc and getting "no transaction is in progress" when trying to call flush() method. 
I can make out that something is wrong with transactions even though i have used @Transactional the method is not running in a transaction.

Spring.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sushant.mvc" />   

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mvc" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="-1" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="-1" />
        <!-- This property should be set to a value so as to support minimum 500 
            BC concurrent connections. For test, set this value to 5 -->
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property> -->
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="user" class="com.sushant.mvc.entities.User"/> -->
</beans>
```

`

User.java

'

```
package com.sushant.mvc.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Entity
@Component
@Configurable
public class User {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "persistenceUnit")
    transient public EntityManager em;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public static final EntityManager entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new User().em;
        if (em == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
        return em;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

'

HomeController.java
'

```
package com.sushant.mvc;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.sushant.mvc.entities.User;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    User user;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is " + locale.toString());
        //user.em.getTransaction().begin();
    //  User user=new User();
        user.setEmail("sushantmahajan05@gmail.com");
        user.setFirstName("Sushant");
        user.setLastName("Mahajan");
        user.setUserName("sushantmahajan05");
        user.save(user);
        User u=user.em.find(User.class, new Integer(1).longValue());
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

        return "home/home";
    }

}
```

'
servlet-context.xml

'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sushant.mvc" />



</beans:beans>
```

'

Comment: Do you have another Spring configuration file for the web application context?

Comment: Do you have Spring DATA JPA repositories and are they scanned using `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />`?

Comment: Yes there is another xml file for dispatcher servlet added above

Comment: no i haven't made any repositories

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating a **persistence.xml** file .

You can take a look at te following example : [JTASessionContext being used with JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456622/jtasessioncontext-being-used-with-jdbctransactionfactory-auto-flush-will-not-op)