# why CAMEL_MESSAGEPROCESSED created in SQL server db

Tags: apache-camel

I want to run Camel built application as stanalone. I am using maven to create standalone jar and execute route.When I run MainApp.java main method from eclipse or run using camel run then code runs as expected. But when I run using java -jar  then 3 tables CAMEL_MESSAGEPROCESSED, CAMEL_MESSAGETRACED,hibernate_sequence are created into db. I do not want these tables created. Please help me find what I am doing wrong.

```
Camel, camel-jpa version 2.19.1 
hibernate-entitymanager version 5.2.7.Final
```

**Camel-context.xml**

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"
            xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.3.xsd 
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
            <bean id="properties" 
                    class="org.apache.camel.component.properti

es.PropertiesComponent">
                <property name="location" value="classpath:db.properties" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" 
                class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
                <property name="location" value="classpath:db.properties" />
        </bean>


        <camelContext id="camel5" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
                <routeBuilder ref="myBuilder" />
        </camelContext>


        <bean id="myBuilder" 
                class="com.aexp.gsnt.insight.updateCentralData.InsightRouterBuilder" />


        <bean id="jpa" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
                <property name="transactionManager" ref="jpaTxManager" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="jpaTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
                                <property name="showSql" value="${showSQL}" />
                                <property name="generateDdl" value="${generateDdl}" />
                        </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="jpaProperties">
                        <props>
                                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${formatSQL}</prop>
                        </props>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource" 
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
                <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        </bean>

</beans>
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
        <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" 
                transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**MainApp.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext; 
public class MainApp { 

        private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext; 

        /* Invoked from Jar */ 
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 
                System.out.println("Started Central Data Extractor"); 
                System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false"); 

                classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml"); 
                classPathXmlApplicationContext.start(); 
        } 

}
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307690/how-to-get-automatic-table-creation-working-in-spring-hibernate-jpa

Comment: Thanks! I used <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>, it is working fine now.